# variable specified in flask not showing up in git pages

Tags: python, variables, github, flask

I specified a variable in my flask app and when the template is rendered, that variable should show up. However, the variable itself does not show up and in its place it instead just says "{{variable}}". How may I fix this.

```
predictions = linear.predict(x_test)
for x in range(len(predictions)):
     print(predictions[x],x_test[x], y_test[x]) #i got rid of 'y_test[x]

output = predictions[x]

p = Flask(__name__)
Bootstrap(app)


@app.route('/')
def math():
    #return(y)
    return render_template('index.html', variable = output)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True)
```

Here is my index:

```
  <section id="services" class="bg-light">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto">
          <h2>Here is the prediction for Tesla stock price</h2>
          <p class="lead">Stock prediction: {{variable}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

here is the live website: https://amanpuranik.github.io/stock2/
here is the github repository: https://github.com/amanpuranik/stock2

any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As described in the [documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.render_template):

> flask.render_template(template_name_or_list, **context)
>
> Renders a template from the template folder with the given context.

The default template folder is *templates/* in your root directory. So you need to put *index.html* into this templates folder if you want it to be rendered.

If you want to change the template folder you can change the parameter *template_folder* when you create your app object as described [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#application-object).

Comment: take a look at my github repo now. I put the index.html in the templates folder but it is still not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you're talking about your website, did you update correctly ? Because it seems correct now

Comment: wait really? When I click on my website I see nothing except the text "stock2" and "stock guru". the template itself isnt being rendered. What do you mean by update correctly?

Comment: As you I see nothing except the text "stock2" etc... I mean you are clearly defined one route "/". Where does the "/stock2" come from?